# Problem with too large intervals in gallery

Tags: css, fancybox

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="gal">
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHVlMCcG_8Q"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/_sI_Ps7JSEk/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://www.hoteljastarnia.com.pl/uploads/gallery/1/11809fjntwefklmnqvwyikost9111525024.jpg"><img src="https://www.hoteljastarnia.com.pl/uploads/gallery/1/11809fjntwefklmnqvwyikost9111525024.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHVlMCcG_8Q"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/_sI_Ps7JSEk/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHVlMCcG_8Q"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/_sI_Ps7JSEk/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://www.hoteljastarnia.com.pl/uploads/gallery/1/22600ijqwzaefghjlmqxbehqt4605389891.jpg"><img src="https://www.hoteljastarnia.com.pl/uploads/gallery/1/22600ijqwzaefghjlmqxbehqt4605389891.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHVlMCcG_8Q"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/_sI_Ps7JSEk/mqdefault.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg"></a>
                    <a data-fancybox = "images" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHVlMCcG_8Q"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/_sI_Ps7JSEk/mqdefault.jpg"></a>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
    .gal {
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }

    .gal img {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        padding-left: 1px;
        padding-right: 1px;
    }

    @media(min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
        .gal {
            -webkit-column-count: 3;
            -moz-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3;
        }
    }

    @media(min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 700px) {
        .gal {
            -webkit-column-count: 2;
            -moz-column-count: 2;
            column-count: 2;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        .gal {
            -webkit-column-count: 1;
            -moz-column-count: 1;
            column-count: 1;
        }
    }
</style>
</body>

</html>
```

Priev: https://jsfiddle.net/pL8qkerw/

I have problem with to large left/right padding vertically, between photos.
I would like both top and bottom padding to be equal.

How to do it?

I still have a question about the titles of photos and videos. Does anyone know how to add a photo or movie title in my code?

Comment: Your style should be in the head, not the body

Comment: Yes, but for example, I've put everything into one document

Comment: This should do the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4fc0d58t/

Comment: Any reason you support ie 8?  Microsoft pulled support a couple of years back and anyone using it will be massively at risk as it won't have been patched in that time